# How to refresh Tab Bar Items in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, reload, uitabbaritem

I do app like `Instagram` with tab bar items. In app I have `simple user` and `company user`.

I have main ViewController:

```
MainTabBarController: UITabBarController
```

with 5 tab bar items. And each item has own `ViewController`

**I need refresh `MainTabBarController` when user is `Simple user` it is 5 items and when user is `Company user` it is 4 items. How to refresh or reload without close app?**

One solution I already do with UserDefaults, but need close app.

**Platform iOS > 9.0, Swift 3.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution:
I divided my **MainTabBarController** to 3 classes:

1. AnonymUserTabBarController. Set 5 tab bar items.
2. SimpleUserTabBarController. Set 5 tab bar items.
3. CompanyTabBarController. Set 4 tab bar items.

And change user UI with animation:

```
func selectCompanyUser() {
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else {
        return
    }

    guard let rootViewController = window.rootViewController else {
        return
    }

    let viewController = CompanyTabBarController()        
    viewController.view.frame = rootViewController.view.frame
    viewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.6, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {
        window.rootViewController = viewController
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [setViewControllers(_:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621177-setviewcontrollers)

```
myTabBarController.setViewControllers(myViewControllers, animated: true)
```

Comment: I think the first line was enough.. :D. It only looked such a small answer, that lead you to add another line.

Comment: just making sure :D

Answer (score 3):

You can post notification to refresh the tabs based on user type, first set the observer in MainTabBarController and once the notification is fired, check the user type and refresh the tabs

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let refreshAllTabs = Notification.Name("RefreshAllTabs")
}

class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .refreshAllTabs, object: nil, queue: .main) { (notification) in
            //check if its a normal user or comapny user
            if AppUser.shared.type == .normal {
                self.viewControllers = [VC1, VC2, VC3, VC4, VC5]
            } else  {
                self.viewControllers = [VC1, VC2, VC3, VC4]
            }
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

now for posting the notification whenever user type changes just call

```
 NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: .refreshAllTabs))
```

Comment: wuuu hold on there with those notifications, you could get yourself into really bad situation.

Comment: It is one of the ways with the problem can be solved, it's a standard apple design pattern. Can you explain how and why it's bad for this situation?

Comment: see my answer above. I may extend method via delegate when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

Usually notifications are really not swifty at all, Swift encourages all programmers to use protocols over Notifications... What about delegation or setting up didSet option for variable? You don't need even the notification at all. I suppose that TabBar is pushed right after the login, so you just make class variable and right in didSet setup the viewControllers:

```
///Considering UserType is enum with cases:
var currentUserType: UserType{
didSet{
currentUserType = .company ? self.viewControllers = /*array with 5 count*/ : self.viewControllers = /*array with 4 counts*/
}
}
```

and now just handle according to viewControllers the rest.